# How to put image and input on the same line with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do something really simple: have image and input on the same line, but can not achieve it:

**HTML**

```
<img src="path/to/img"/>
<input/>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    height: 50px;
}
input {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

As you clearly see from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SVLEJ/), image is much higher than the input. How can I fix it?

Comment: What you are looking for is Floats. You can read more about Floats here: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ You may also want to look into the css box model as well: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property:

```
img{
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/SVLEJ/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve the effect you are looking for with floats:

```
img{
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
input{
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SVLEJ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align`, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/SVLEJ/5/):

```
img{
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
input{
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set float on the `img` [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/SVLEJ/4/):

```
img{
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
}
input{
    height: 50px;
}
```