# Show image next to input rather than underneath it

Tags: html, css

So, I wanted to display a loading gif when an input box was on focus.
I've managed to do it but the loading gif it's getting below the input box, and not after
On CSS, if I change the `display:none` to `display:yes` the loading gif appears after the input box as I want, but only until the JS function is triggered.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('showloading');
var message = document.getElementsByClassName('loadingGif')[0];
input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  message.style.display = 'block';
});
input.addEventListener('focusout', function() {
  message.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
.loadingGif {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="showloading" type="text" class="auto">
<img class="loadingGif" src="loading.gif">
```

**Screenshoots:**

What it looks like:

[image: What it looks like]

What I want it to look like:

[image: What I want it to look like]

Comment: just make sure there is enough space after your input for the gif to fit on that line

Comment: The question has nothing to do with JavaScript other than that you're assigning `display: block`. You need to update your HTML and/or CSS to put the image next to the input rather than underneath it.

Comment: Read about [`block` in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Block/CSS)

Comment: Not related to your display issue, but you don't need javascript to achieve this result, you can solve it using css only, with a rule like `input:focus ~ .loadingGif {display: inline-block}`

Comment: besides the required space for the image. Look at  float:left for the input element

Comment: @Pepper I've changed the JS ` message.style.display = 'block';` to ` message.style.display = 'inline-block';` and it worked, thank you!

Comment: Btw there was indeed space for the gif (as shown of the 2nd picture...)

Comment: @CarlosSantiago yes, `display: block` is the reason why it didn't stay in the same line, but what I meant is that you can get rid of your javascript entirely^^ (like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ntvyr65j/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put image and input on the same line with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520295/how-to-put-image-and-input-on-the-same-line-with-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `block` is displayed as a block, so it starts a new visual line.

I wouldn't use `style` at all, I'd use a class to show/hide the image:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('showloading');
var message = document.getElementsByClassName('loadingGif')[0];
input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  message.classList.remove("hide"); // <===
});
input.addEventListener('focusout', function() {
  message.classList.add("hide"); // <===
});
```

```css
.loadingGif.hide {
/* --------^^^^^   */
  display: none; /* <=== */
}
```

```html
<input id="showloading" type="text" class="auto">
<img class="loadingGif hide" src="loading.gif">
<!-- ------------------^^^^   -->
```

...although as [Pepper says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59826632/show-image-next-to-input-rather-than-underneath-it/59826770#comment105790142_59826632) (and [Diogo also now says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59826872/157247)), you can do this with just CSS and without JavaScript or a class.

Answer (score 4):

@T.J. Crowder aswer is the one you should follow if you want to use Javascript although you don't need Javascript to do what you want.
You can use only CSS by using `:focus` selector and the sibling selector `+` to write a style rule. When `showloading` is focused all the adjacent siblings with the class `loadingGif` will have the `display: inline-block`

Such as:

```css
.loadingGif {
  display: none;
}
 
#showloading:focus + .loadingGif {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input id="showloading" type="text" class="auto">
<img class="loadingGif" src="loading.gif">
```